# Access current value as property value of an object - Javascript Foreach

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, lodash

I have an array. I loop over that array. How to use the current value as a property inside a map function inside  a for loop?

```js
    var abc = ['FRUITS', 'COLORS', 'CARS', 'COMPUTERS'];

    var cars = [{
      name: "Saab",
      CARS: 'Saab 9 -5'
    }, {
      name:"Volvo",
      CARS: 'XC 60'
    }, {
      name: "BMW",
      CARS: '5 Series'
    }];

    _.forEach(abc, (item, index) => {

      if (item === 'CARS') {
        var car = _.map(cars, (car) => {
        
        return car.item
        })
        console.log(car)
      }
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.js"></script>
```

As you see, in the map function I carry out, I use a .item and that {{item}} should be from the parent loop. Here item should refer to "CARS"

Please advice.

Comment: The cars Objects don't have an `item` key. You probably want `return car[item]`.

Comment: Yes, but how do I dynamically refer to the item from the for loop as in the current state item === 'CARS'

Comment: In addition to what @ChrisG said, the cars array is.. all cars.  What's your desired end result?

Comment: Got it. Bracked notation worked. Thanks guys